# Receive data from HTTP GET and send it to a webpage

Tags: php, node.js, get, webhooks

I have a sensor that can send HTTP GET requests containing data. I want to receive this data and send it to a webpage. I want the webpage to update when we get new data. We get new data about every 2 minutes. I want the data to be as up-to-date as possible.

- How do i accept the incoming push from the sensor?
- How do i take that and update the webpage?

Currently I'm querying the sensor for data, but that is putting too much load on the sensor as every user who has a webpage open is constantly making requests to the sensor. This is the reason I'd like to switch to having the sensor send the data out on set intervals. I've been reading about SSE and web-hooks etc. but need some direction on tying this all together.

Answer (score 0):

Just in your procces
http://localhost?id=1

```
$_GET['id'];
```

And
in youur view

```
<?php echo "$_GET['id']";?>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't follow your answer. Can you clarify? I'm not sure how to setup the process you talking about is that like a PHP? And will that php update the view without refreshing the page?